# How to align node labels in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I use [this](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/filesystem-tree/) code to draw filesystem trees, and also I use node labels to add descriptions.

The question is how to align node labels? I can add descriptions as separate nodes and use relative positioning, but it is tedious.

bad:

```
node1    description
  node2    description
    node3    description
```

good:

```
node1        description
  node2      description
    node3    description
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw=black,thick,anchor=west]
\tikzstyle{selected}=[draw=red,fill=red!30]
\tikzstyle{optional}=[dashed,fill=gray!50]
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    grow via three points={one child at (0.5,-0.7) and
    two children at (0.5,-0.7) and (0.5,-1.4)},
    edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) |- (\tikzchildnode.west)}]
    \node [label={right:description}] {texmf}
        child { node [label={right:description}] {doc}}     
        child { node [label={right:description}] {fonts}}
        child { node [label={right:description}] {source}}
        child { node [selected,label={right:description}] {tex}
        child { node [label={right:description}] {generic}}
        child { node [optional,label={right:description}] {latex}}
        child { node [label={right:description}] {plain}}
    }
    child [missing,label={right:description}c] {}               
    child [missing,label={right:description}] {}                
    child [missing,label={right:description}] {}                
    child { node [label={right:description}] {texdoc}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define a new node called `descriptionheader`, say, and then position the description nodes at the same horizontal position as that new node using `shift={(0,0-|descriptionheader.west)}` in the `label` options:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw=black,thick,anchor=west]
\tikzstyle{selected}=[draw=red,fill=red!30]
\tikzstyle{optional}=[dashed,fill=gray!50]
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    grow via three points={one child at (0.5,-0.7) and
    two children at (0.5,-0.7) and (0.5,-1.4)},
    edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) |- (\tikzchildnode.west)},
    every label/.append style={shift={(0,0-|descriptionheader.west)}}
    ]
    \node (descriptionheader) [draw=none, font=\bfseries] at (4,4ex) {Descriptions};
    \node [label={right:description}] {texmf}
        child { node [label={right:long description}] {doc}}     
        child { node [label={right:description}] {fonts}}
        child { node [label={right:description}] {source}}
        child { node [selected,label={right:description}] {tex}
        child { node [label={right:description}] {generic}}
        child { node [optional,label={right:description}] {latex}}
        child { node [label={right:description}] {plain}}
    }
    child [missing,label={right:description}c] {}               
    child [missing,label={right:description}] {}                
    child [missing,label={right:description}] {}                
    child { node [label={right:description}] {texdoc}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```